# Laravel 4 - Setting up routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I'm working on a site I have inherited and having a little trouble routing to a controller.

When I visit the URL www.domain.com/banners/statistics, it won't return anything.

I also noted that when I try and link to this page via Banner Statistics this also gives me an error on my home page.

Routes.php

```
Route::resource('banners', 'BannerController');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/activate', 'BannerController@activate');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/deactivate', 'BannerController@deactivate');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/delete', 'BannerController@delete');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/preview', 'BannerController@preview');
Route::any('banners/{banners}/cropresize', 'BannerController@cropresize');
Route::get('banners/statistics', 'BannerController@statistics');
```

BannerController.php

```
public function create()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Create Banner';
        $data['disciplines'] = Discipline::lists('name', 'id');
        return View::make('admin.banners.create', $data);
    }

    public function statistics()
    {
      return View::make('admin.banners.statistics');
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you post the code in your view: `app/views/admin/banners/statistics`?

Comment: Ah, the error in my view referred to a different function completely so that is fixed now - no errors.  Strangely though I'm still not having it route correctly.  Even adding   return "test"; in my function doesn't return anything

Comment: I should point out that the only way I seem to be able to make it route in any way, is if I add Route::get('banners/statistics/{company}', 'BannerController@statistics'); and then public function statistics($companyId) in my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource controller provides you multiple routes.

Including :

`GET    /resource/{resource}` redirecting to the show action of your controller.

*List of all created routes :* *http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers*

So when you call

> banners/statistics

Laravel think you want to call the show action with "statistics" as a parameter.

To avoid this, you can put all your custom routes above your resource controller route.

```
Route::get('banners/{banners}/activate', 'BannerController@activate');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/deactivate', 'BannerController@deactivate');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/delete', 'BannerController@delete');
Route::get('banners/{banners}/preview', 'BannerController@preview');
Route::any('banners/{banners}/cropresize', 'BannerController@cropresize');
Route::get('banners/statistics', 'BannerController@statistics');
Route::resource('banners', 'BannerController');
```

This way Laravel will call your custom route before the routes created by your resource controller.

You can also use `only` and `except` if you don't need some of the resource controller routes.

```
Route::resource('banners', 'BannerController',
                array('except' => array('show')));
```

Comment: Of course, it all makes sense now.  I think I need to read up a little more on routing. :-) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It's sometime tricky to avoid conflicts when you have a lot of routes.